# kubectl get pods failing and getting html in response

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubectl

My kubectl get pods fails with below error

```
:=> kubectl get pods
E1108 11:09:42.145784   40291 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
E1108 11:09:42.472168   40291 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
E1108 11:09:42.784266   40291 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
E1108 11:09:43.109982   40291 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
E1108 11:09:43.439883   40291 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
error: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
~:=>
```

I tried `kubectl -v 10 version` and I do get html back. I am pasting just the first few lines though therse do not have any error

```
I1108 11:10:58.894044   40346 loader.go:373] Config loaded from file:  /Users/ksachdev/.kube/config
I1108 11:10:58.895822   40346 round_trippers.go:466] curl -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.27.5 (darwin/arm64) kubernetes/728cd79" 'https://<ip>/version?timeout=32s'
I1108 11:10:59.057695   40346 round_trippers.go:510] HTTP Trace: Dial to tcp:<ip>:443 succeed
I1108 11:10:59.232930   40346 round_trippers.go:553] GET https://<ip>/version?timeout=32s 302 Moved Temporarily in 336 milliseconds
I1108 11:10:59.233072   40346 round_trippers.go:570] HTTP Statistics: DNSLookup 0 ms Dial 159 ms TLSHandshake 163 ms ServerProcessing 8 ms Duration 336 ms
I1108 11:10:59.233131   40346 round_trippers.go:577] Response Headers:
I1108 11:10:59.233176   40346 round_trippers.go:580]     Location: https://sv3-mfa.<domain>.com:6082/php/uid.php?vsys=1&rule=29&token=HIIdPjZfP6EZgYSkmf0CfWcn7EY=&url=https://<ip>%2fversion%3ftimeout%3d32s
I1108 11:10:59.233226   40346 round_trippers.go:580]     Content-Length: 0
I1108 11:10:59.233262   40346 round_trippers.go:580]     Pragma: no-cache
I1108 11:10:59.233310   40346 round_trippers.go:580]     Cache-Control: no-cache
```

I am trying to connect to gcp based k8 cluster from laptop. Sometimes a reboot fixes the problem but it comes back.

Also, I had installed minikube and `krew` from `https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/krew/` I do not think minikube is running currently either.

I do authenticate to gcp via cli and that call succeeds as below

```
Credentials saved to file: [/mydir/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json]

These credentials will be used by any library that requests Application Default Credentials (ADC).
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information at hand, there are a lot of point you need to check in order to figure out the cause of the issue and troubleshoot. Look like there is a redirect that is occurring which is causing the HTML response. You may want to check the network components such as Loadbalancer(if there is any), proxy settings and firewalls. You mentioned that it works after restart but re-occurs, try clearing the cache for both kubectl and also check if all settings are up to date. Here are some docs that can be useful and I hope these recommendations help your use case.[1][2]

[1] https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/

[2] https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/